# Can an Azure Table have only PartitionID and RowKey

Tags: azure-table-storage

I'm designing an application that depends on Azure Table. I would like to design my tables such that it has only partitionid and rowkey and no other field (attribute). Is that allowed in the Azure Table?

Btw, is it allowed to have multiple records with the same (partitionid and rowkey)?

Answer (score 0):

Just Partition Key and Row Key is fine for an entity. Given that the pk/rk are the identifiers it doesn't make sense though to have multiple records with the same pk/rk combo. Please see the [general concept docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx) on table for more information.

Comment: let's assume it makes sense in an application, so is it allowed to have multiple records with same pk/rk?

Comment: I'm saying it isn't possible on the service. If you check out the general concept docs it goes over why this doesn't make sense from a service perspective. The relevant quote from the doc listed is 'Together the PartitionKey and RowKey uniquely identify every entity within a table.'